# React Native TextInput стилизовать маску

Tags: javascript, react-native, mask

Использую плагин [react-native-masked-text](https://github.com/benhurott/react-native-masked-text)

[image: Сделал такой вот инпут, теперь мне нужно при фокусе заменять xxxxx на ____]

Сделал такой вот инпут, теперь мне нужно при фокусе заменять xxxxx на ____

Не знаю как это сделать

Answer (score 0):

Так как примера кода самого нет, пример из документации возьму, как понял рассматриваем `type={'custom'}`:

```
<TextInputMask
  type={'custom'}
  options={options}

  // dont forget to set the "value" and "onChangeText" props
  value={this.state.text}
  onChangeText={text => {
    this.setState({
      text: text
    })
  }}
/>
```

Получается `options` на событии `onFocus` должен меняться, то есть, примерно должно быть так:

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState({
   // тут настройки при отображении без фокуса, где маска ХХХ
});
```

и в

```
onFocus={() => setOptions({
   // новые конфиги, где маска не XXX, а ___
})}
```